# Validate payload against header Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, versioning

I have various versions on my API. So, for example, I have the accept header as center_1.1.
When I pass this header with a previous version of the payload I would like to throw an exception, showing the user that the path is wrong. So, for example, for version center_1.0, the payload should be as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "city": "Campinas",
     ...
  }
}
```

And for payload of version center_1.1, should be:

```
{
  "data": {
    "route": "Campinas",
     ...
  }
}
```

When I send for example, the header as center_1.1 and the payload of version 1.0, I would like to give the user an error, showing that data.city path is wrong.

I've tried making this:

```
  public <T extends ... > void validateExpectedPayloadVersion(JsonApi<T> payload, String version)
      throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);


    oos.writeObject(payload);

    oos.flush();
    oos.close();

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

    try (InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
      JsonApi<T> payloadRequest;
      try {
        payloadRequest= unmarshallToVersion(streamReader, version);
      } catch (final UnrecognizedPropertyException e) {

        final String offendingPath = StringUtils
            .join(e.getPath().stream().map(JsonMappingException.Reference::getFieldName)
                .collect(
                    Collectors.toList()), ".");

        throw new InvalidException(offendingPath);
      }
    }

  }

  private <T extends ...> JsonApi<T> unmarshallToVersion(final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader,
      final String version)
      throws IOException {

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    switch (version) {
      case "center.1.0":
        return (JsonApi<T>) mapper.readValue(inputStreamReader, new TypeReference<JsonApi<CenterDtoV0>>() {});
      case "center.1.1":
      default:
        return (JsonApi<T>) mapper.readValue(inputStreamReader, new TypeReference<JsonApi<CenterDtoV1>>() {});
    }
  }
```

But this won't throw the desired exception (UnrecognizedPropertyException).

Comment: Why not use a filter that performs the header check?

Comment: But how would I know that the payload is in the version I want?

Comment: You can check your header information and request in your filter.

Comment: I checked the `unmarshallToVersion` method. You are not throwing any `UnrecognizedPropertyException` exceptions here. So it's perfectly normal that you're not getting an exception.

Comment: Right. But how can I do this? I'm also having this problem as I'm using generics.

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is to throw that conversion error: ```return (JsonApi<T>) mapper.readValue(inputStreamReader, new TypeReference<JsonApi<CenterDtoV1>>() {});```